# How to apply template in Automatic Recode in SPSS?

Tags: statistics, spss, spss-modeler

I have saved template (`.sat) file, but cannot apply it. When I apply it, the OK button is still disabled. Please see the image:

[image]

Could this be because of the trial version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're within the 14-day trial period, you have everything available to you, so it isn't the license.

1). A common mistake is to forget to fill in the "New Name" field. Make sure you have done that and clicked 'Add New Name'. Until you do, OK is disabled.

2). Apart from that, if you haven't tried in syntax, then could you please start the program and try something like this:

```
DATA LIST FREE /x (F1) a (A1).
BEGIN DATA.
1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5 e
END DATA.
DATASET NAME data1.

AUTORECODE VARIABLES=a /INTO na
  /SAVE TEMPLATE='<your path>/template.sat'
  /PRINT.

DATA LIST FREE /y (F1) a (A1).
BEGIN DATA.
1 a 2 e 3 d 4 a 5 c 6 b 7 c 8 e 9 g 10 z
END DATA.
DATASET NAME data2.

DATASET ACTIVATE data2.
AUTORECODE VARIABLES=a /INTO na
  /APPLY TEMPLATE='<your path>/template.sat'
  /PRINT.
```

If you get an error with AUTORECODE then there is a problem with your installation; please reply with whatever the error message is.